# Referencing Case Status attributes in validation rule

Tags: case, validation, status

Is there a way to determine within a validation rule whether a Case Status has changed from an Open picklist value to a Closed picklist without referencing every single picklist value?

I want to prevent closing a case from a validation rule but we have many different statuses. Similarly new statuses may be added in the future and I don't want to have to update the validation rule when a new one is created. The IsClosed field exists on case but is a case that only returns a true value AFTER later in the DML transaction.

The validation rule I'd like to write would look something like this

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(Status),
PRIORVALUE(An_Open_Value)
Status=A_Closed_Value
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to create a new (technical) checkbox on Case and create a RTF before flow to (un)check the new checkbox.

Tech design would be:

- Create a new field on Case(checkbox, name "TEC Is Closed", don't show on any layout)
- Create new Record Triggered Flow on Case, before insert/update

  - Use "Get" element to query `CaseStatus` object with filter "ApiName = Case.Status"
  - Use "Assignment" element to set `TecIsClosed__c` field equal to `CaseStatus.IsClosed` from the "Get" element
- Create a new Validation Rule on Case to check if a Case was just closed:

```
AND(
  ISCHANGED(TecIsClosed__c),  // Check if the checkbox changed value
  TecIsClosed__c // Check that the checkbox is checked now
)
```